# Is it considered better practice to change an object with a member function or return it and assign it?

Tags: c++

First of all, sorry if the question is worded poorly, I wasn't sure how best to phrase it. Also I should note that the code I am writing is designed to be used by others, so readability and ease of use are key.

Let's say I have a class, vec3, that contains a member function called normalize. I see two options for how to operate this function. I can use the function to normalize the data contained within the object itself, or I can create a new normalized vec3 within the function and return it.

Now obviously both of these functions would have their uses, but what I am wondering is if there is a standard practice for this sort of thing. Obviously returning a new object is more flexible as I can always assign the new object to the object:

```
v = v.normalize();

vec3 vec3::normalize(){
    vec3 r = *this;
    double s = sqrt(r.x*r.x + r.y*r.y + r.z*r.z);
    if(s<1e-8){
        r.x=0.0; r.y=0.0; r.z=0.0;
    }
    else{
        x /= s;
        y /= s;
        z /= s;        
    }
    return r;

}
```

Now perhaps modern compilers might optimize this out, but if I will almost always be using this function in this way, it seems more efficient to just change the object within the function.

```
v.normalize()

void vec3::normalize(){
    double s = sqrt(x*x + y*y + z*z);
    if(s<1e-8){
        x=0.0; y=0.0; z=0.0;
    }
    else{
        x /= s;
        y /= s;
        z /= s;        
    }
}
```

Now I could create two different functions, one to return a value and one to change the value, but doing this for every function seems like overkill, and I wouldn't be sure how to differentiate well between them for the users.

Now obviously a lot of these questions could come down to simply the personal preferences of the programmer, but if there is any standard practice for this kind of problem I would really appreciate some tips.

Thanks.

Comment: I think this is a question of mutability vs immutability and it's mostly up to you to decide based on the use cases of these methods. The questions is, do you need the original array after normalizing it, if yes you need to make a copy, if not, you don't. In most cases of matrix processing, such as the openCV vision library, immutability is preferred as it leaves the user free to build matrix processing pipelines that can branch into two distinct streams without having to explicitly create copies.

Comment: "*doing this for every function seems like overkill*" There aren't all that many mathematical mutating functions you can apply to a 3D vector.

Comment: @NicolBolas While having multiple functions for a simple vec3 might not be that crazy, it will get much worse with more complicated classes. The reason I asked this question was because of only a simple 4x4 matrix class that will be used for OpenGL and already the number of functions for even that relatively simple class is getting very large, and it will only get worse. This was just an example.

Comment: @CameronAtkinson: "*already the number of functions for even that relatively simple class is getting very large*" Which is why most everybody else just uses GLM. Writing and testing code instead of using someone else's written and tested code isn't going to make your project get done faster.

Comment: I would expect that a function that's called `normalize()` will normalize the object it's called on. And I would expect a function called `normalized()` to return a normalized object and not modify the object it's called on. Choose good names for your functions.

Comment: @NikosC.: "*And I would expect a function called `normalized()` to return a normalized object and not modify the object it's called on.*" I wouldn't. Indeed, the use of past-tense here suggests that this function is verifying that the object has already been "normalized".

Comment: @NicolBolas Anything related to checks of "is" or "isn't" should begin with `is`. In this case, `is_normalized()`. A good coding standard will require this naming convention.

Comment: @NikosC.: "*A good coding standard will require this naming convention.*" But you cannot *assume* that. There's plenty of C++ code that defies it, including most of the *C++ standard library*. So a reader would have to look up the documentation to see what your function is actually doing. And even ignoring that, "normalized" is not a verb; it's a state of being. It's not an action being performed on something; it's a description of what it is. It's just not the right word for a function that performs an action, whether in-situ or on a copy.

Answer (score 2):

*Very broadly speaking*, if a function is a member function, and it is named in such a way as to suggest an operation which mutates the object, then it probably does/should. `vector::clear` does not return an empty vector; it clears the current vector.

If there is a `normalize` function on a vector type, I would say that people will reasonably assume that it is normalizing the vector itself.

Now, that's hardly universal. Indeed, it's not even universally true of just the standard library. `basic_string::substr` does not convert the string into a subset of itself; it *returns* a new string which is a subset of the original.

So it will generally be dealer's choice. But that doesn't mean that readers of your class will not make assumptions, and the general assumption will be that member functions which seem like they mutate the object probably do. `a = a.normalize()` looks a bit weird.

By contrast, if `normalize` is a non-member function, it is reasonable to assume that it is returning a normalized vector, not normalizing the vector in-situ. The reason being that, if it mutated in-situ, you wouldn't be able to do something like this:

```
normalize(a + b);
```

People will generally assume that this will work. But if its mutating, it doesn't; it will return a reference to a temporary, which will be destroyed at the end of the expression.

By contrast, `(a + b).normalize()`, while technically possible, looks really bizarre and things like that are almost always a code smell. Unless you consume that vector later in the same expression, you will get a reference to a *destroyed* object.

That's bad. And experienced C++ programmers know that in pretty much every case, code that looks like this (calling a member function on a temporary) is doing this bad thing.

So if you're going for a mutating member function, there are two things to keep in mind: making `(a + b).normalize()` fail to compile, and return `*this` at the end, so that users can chain functions as needed. For example:

```
vec3 &vec3::normalize() & //Prevents the use of this function on prvalues.
{
    double s = sqrt(x*x + y*y + z*z);
    if(s<1e-8){
        x=0.0; y=0.0; z=0.0;
    }
    else{
        x /= s;
        y /= s;
        z /= s;        
    }
    return *this;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What should be the interface of a class? It is totally depends on class and what it is representing.
For example if i consider your function `vec3::normalize()`, i would say `normalize()` should not modify object, because it is not taking any input from user and this normalization can be done in constructor itself.
Now consider a situation if someone call `normalize()` function more then once, then what will happen? and would you like to handle this situation? It means `normalize()` function should return a new object rather than modifying object.
Let's consider `QRect` class of `Qt`, it offers two functions 
`QRect QRect::normalized() const` It performs, *"Returns a normalized rectangle; i.e., a rectangle that has a non-negative width and height.
If width() < 0 the function swaps the left and right corners, and it swaps the top and bottom corners if height() < 0."* and this method return a new object.
second method `void QRect::adjust(int dx1, int dy1, int dx2, int dy2)` and it performs, *"Adds dx1, dy1, dx2 and dy2 respectively to the existing coordinates of the rectangle."*
So from these two functions, i can conclude if i want to perform some logic on object and wants to keep the change then i shall go for function which modify the object, and if i want to perform some logic on object and don't want any modification in it (object state should not change) then i shall go from function which return new object.

Comment: "*because it is not taking any input from user*" It is taking input. It takes `this`, the current object of type `vec3` to normalize. Furthermore in C++, functions that take explicit parameters do not typically modify them. "*this normalization can be done in constructor itself*" I don't know what you mean by this; what "constructor" are you discussing here?

Comment: "*Let's consider QRect class of Qt, it offers two functions*" Also, this discussion seems kind of moot. You can see that "normalized" is a `const` function, so it *cannot* modify the current object. Therefore, the only possible thing it can do is return a "normalized" value. So yes, if you look at a function *declaration*, you know what's going on. But the case here is focused on just the name. You *could* track down the declaration via the IDE or whatever, but the point of the question is to get an intuitive idea of what a function ought to do without having to look it up.

Comment: The point i want to make here is, if you have a use case when you want a new object to be cloned form an existing object  by applying some logic then go for a function which return new object, and if you only wants to change the state of your object then go for a function which modifies object.

Comment: But... that's not the question. The question isn't what are the options for such a function (return a new value or mutate the object). The question is which behavior should the function actually provide, which one is more "standard" or whatever.